# how to kill process inside the kernel itself not from the user level

Tags: syslinux

I am trying to kill a specific process from the kernel (not in the user level)
so I was trying to use sys_kill, kill, kill_pid
but it did not work
the only one did not give me an error is kill_pid but it did not kill the process that I asked
so any help in that?

Comment: No you cant. You are in userspace. glibc or shell cant do that. That is why linux is more secure than windows.

Comment: I am writing the code not playing in the shall

Comment: Whatever code you are writing, you still executing it in userspace. You still use library to interact with kernel. In linux no direct access to kernel space.

Answer (score 2):

No you cant. You are in userspace. glibc or shell cant do that. That is why linux is more secure than windows.

Signal only works in userspace, so there is no way you can stop kernel thread